# Use two background threads in same activity

Tags: android

i want to make an api call and then i want to use data(url) given by api to display the image in grid view.Both these task must use background thread but I don't know how to use two threads in same activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask,
Here is the tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html